# How do I exchange an Auth Code goole for a Token in spring boot backend?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I am working on Vuejs / spring boot application with oauth2 authentication.
in the front side i'm calling the google API with my CLIENT_ID to get the AUTH CODE after that i don't know how to exchange this AUTH CODE with TOKEN OR JSESSION on spring boot to access the secure backend API

Comment: this may require a little bit more effort. You have showed no code that people can look at

Comment: The result from a successfull OAUTH call should be the token.

Comment: thank you for your replies i created another question with the code this is the link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60787366/how-do-i-exchange-an-auth-code-goole-for-a-token-in-spring-boot-state-paramete .

Comment: Work through out this https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2

Comment: Did u manage to solve this? Using spring security + spring oauth2 client  + spring boot, i manage to get the authorisation code.  I am using oauth2Login api.  So how to exchange this code with token?